# Error con el Seed en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Disculpen tengo una duda, a lo mejor es algo muy sencillo pero siento que ya me encerré en mi error y no puedo mirar otra solución
la cuestión es la siguiente:
 tengo mis tablas o migraciones:
 *rangos

```
  Schema::create('rangos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('inicio');
        $table->unsignedInteger('final');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

*articulos

```
     Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('codigo');
        $table->string('SKU');
        $table->string('descripcion',75)->unique();
        $table->double('precioUnitario');
        $table->boolean('a_venta');
        $table->boolean('a_inventario');
        $table->boolean('a_compra');
        $table->boolean('act_fijo');
        $table->string('file',128)->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_grupo');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_area');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_clase');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_lista');
        $table->foreign('id_grupo')->references('id')->on('grupos')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_area')->references('id')->on('areas')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_clase')->references('id')->on('clases')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_lista')->references('id')->on('lista_precios')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

*articulo_rango

```
     Schema::create('articulo_rango', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');            
        $table->double('precio');
        $table->unsignedInteger('articulo_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('rango_id');

        $table->timestamps();

        //relaciones
        $table->foreign('articulo_id')->references('id')->on('articulos')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('rango_id')->references('id')->on('rangos')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Entonces al hacer mi factory y mi seeds

me genera los datos falsos pero no puedo ingresar lo que es el atributo precio en mi database

esto es mi seed

```
    factory(App\Articulo::class, 160)->create()->each(function(App\Articulo $articulo){
        $articulo->rango()->attach([
            rand(1,5),
            rand(6,15),
            rand(16, 23),

        ]);
    });
```

aclaro ya cree los belongsToMany

*esto es en mi model articulo

```
   public function rango(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rango::class)->withPivot('precio');
    }
```

*esto es en mi model rango

```
   public function articulo(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Articulo::class)->withPivot('precio');
    }
```

espero y me ayuden par generar mis datos falsos

soy nuevo en esto.. saludos

este es el error 
  [image: esto es el error ocacionado al ejecutar php artisna migrate:refresh --seed]

Comment: Segun lo que veo del error es que 'precio' no puede ser un valor null, tiene que ingresarle algo, en cualquier caso puedes poner `->nulleable()` y ves lo que te arroja

Comment: Según el error parece que al poblar la db no se están agregando datos en el campo 'precio' de la tabla 'articulo_rango'. Como ese campo no es nulo y no tiene un valor por defecto por eso falla.

Comment: Puedes usar navicat, dbeaver, phpmyadmin o la herramienta que gustes para ajustar manualmente ese campo para darle un valor por defecto o mejor revisar por qué no se guarda correctamente ese valor.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta indicar que la columna tenga un valor por default o que sea nulo:

Valor por default `$table->double('precio')->default(0);`
Valor nulo `$table->double('precio')->nullable();`

Comment: de hecho asi lo tengo ahorita y no lo especifique tampoco .. pero quisiera que se llena con el seeds por que al tener el default 0 o  nullable, no se me registra en la base de datos

Comment: Pues puedes hacer  la migración de nuevo y luego el seed, o puedes ir al  phpAdmin y editar el campo para que te deje hacer el seed

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez es porque te falta especificar los dos parámetros adicionales al `double`.

*Ejemplo:*

```
$table->double('column', 15, 8);
```

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, en esta cuestion me marca error al poner parametros o longitud a mi atributo, yem indica que deberia ser float (y) muchas grcias